# 1099-B Proceeds/Cost Basis reported incorrectly? Or user error?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, 1099-b

I was trying to enter my 1099B's from Robinhood into Credit Karma Tax....

The short version of the issue is that I made ~$4k this year, but the 1099B's I have seem to have a cost basis $32,000 higher than my proceeds.... I don't understand how.

Robinhood send out two different 1099B's this year, due to an internal change in their providers, but I've posted numbers from both below.

[image: First 1099B]

[image: Second 1099B]

The Realized Gain or Loss section shows the appropriate numbers, where I've profited ~$4400. However there's a ***huge*** gap between the cost basis and proceeds, and Credit Karma Tax wants this information entered with the sales price and cost basis.

[image: CKarma input form]

I feel like this should be fairly straight forward, but clearly I must be missing something? I'll reach out to their support to figure out what's going on as well but figured I'd post here to see if I'm making some kind of stupid math mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer was right in front of me..... The 'Wash Sale Loss Disallowed' bit was to be summed with the other numbers to get the gain/loss.... This explains the difference.

**Note:** Accounting for this specifically in Credit Karma Tax involves adding the Wash Sale amount as an Adjustment and marking it with Adjustment Code W.